# Angular 2 Reverse Proxy - Different context path

Tags: angular, reverse-proxy, weblogic12c

I am using a `Weblogic Application Server`, where I have deployed my `Angular 2`application.

lets assume that the **internal IP** is `http://127.0.0.1:7009/myapp`, and I have set

But the application is exposed external from a Reverse Proxy at `http://my.application.org/myapp2`.

So we have 2 different context paths. This causes problems since I cannot find my front-end resources. How do we resolve such a problem?